# OpenCV java. Multiple images side by side

Tags: java, opencv

Is there any example of how to combine two or more images side by side? **In JAVA**

I tried to adapt c++ code but without success.

```
Mat m = new Mat(imageA.cols(), imageA.rows() + imageB.rows(), imageA.type());

m.adjustROI(0, 0, imageA.cols(), imageA.rows());
imageA.copyTo(m);

m.adjustROI(0, imageA.rows(), imageB.cols(), imageB.rows());
imageB.copyTo(m);
```

This will always give `m` as `imageA`. Method `A.copyTo(B)` always result like `B == A`

Almost every example in c++ contains `cvCopy(arg1, arg2);` it looks like java analog is A.copyTo(B)

But when I use A.copyTo(B), I always get image with width, height and content of A even if B was bigger.

Comment: your adjusted ROI has the wrong dimensions; it should be sized to fit imageA, not `m` (which is causing it to be an invalid window, and therefore probably ignored or throwing an exception). For the future, please always give more detail than "without success"

Comment: @Dave I updated the post. Do I need to set ROI? Seems that method A.copyTo(B) just makes Mat B == Mat A and does not take into account ROI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private Mat addTo(Mat matA, Mat matB) {
    Mat m = new Mat(matA.rows(), matA.cols() +  matB.cols(), matA.type());
    int aCols = matA.cols();
    int aRows = matA.rows();
    m.rowRange(0, aRows-1).colRange(0, aCols-1) = matA;
    m.rowRange(0, aRows-1).colRange(aCols, (aCols*2)-1) = matB;
    return m;
}
```

I didn't try to run it, but I believe it will work. I assume `matA` and matB will have *same size* and *same type*. Even if it doesn't work, there must be some little syntax errors or etc. **You shouldn't be putting pixels values by using 4 for loops!**

Comment: Thank you, looks like better solution (haven't tried it yet), will return here if it will not work and give a comment on

Comment: I had some problems when trying to adapt this code. I think the actual parameters should be something like `rowRange(0, aRows)`, the final index is the first after the last, as in the regular way of specifying ranges...

Answer (score 3):

You can actually use hconcat/vconcat functions:

```
Mat dst = new Mat();
List<Mat> src = Arrays.asList(mat1, mat2);
Core.hconcat(src, dst);
//Core.vconcat(src, dst);
```