# Combine images using openCV in Java (and looking for openCv Java Docs)

Tags: java, opencv, image-processing

I would like to simply combine two images with same size side by side into a new one. I found answers in `C++` but when my translation into java does not work as expected, and my guess is that the `Mat.copyTo()` in two languages work differently.

I also found exactly same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23593443/opencv-java-multiple-images-side-by-side) but the answer code does not work.

By the way, is there anywhere I can find `openCV` documents (v2.4) in Java?

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Function [hconcat](http://docs.opencv.org/java/org/opencv/core/Core.html#hconcat(java.util.List,%20org.opencv.core.Mat)) can be used for horizontal concatenation of images / matrices

```
Mat img_left, img_right;
Mat dst = new Mat();
List<Mat> src = Arrays.asList(img_left, img_right);
Core.hconcat(src, dst);
```

Answer (score 0):

All right, I have found my problem. By using Mat.submat() and Mat.copyTo I achieved what I wanted. The reason it did not work is that the format of the combined image mat and the original ones are different, and openCV did not note the miss match.